# Lua error "attempt to call global" on Wireshark dissector when using loadstring()

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to execute a custom function call dynamically defined using loadstring inside a Wireshark dissector.

When using this method from inside another similar Lua script, it works fine:

```
function ftest(s)
  return s..s
end

k="knock "
fcallstr="rs = ftest(k)"
loadstring(fcallstr)()
print("now rs = " .. rs)

--now rs = knock knock
```

But if I try to do the same based on the dissector example (https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors), I get an error:

```
function mycustomfnc(buffer, subtree)
  print(os.time() .. "  " .. "FUNCTION REACHED!")
  subtree:add(buffer(4,2),"Plus 5th and 6th bytes!: " .. buffer(4,2):uint())
end


-- declare our protocol
trivial_proto = Proto("trivial","Trivial Protocol")
-- create a function to dissect it
function trivial_proto.dissector(buffer,pinfo,tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = "TRIVIAL"
    local subtree = tree:add(trivial_proto,buffer(),"Trivial Protocol Data")
    subtree:add(buffer(0,2),"The first two bytes: " .. buffer(0,2):uint())
    subtree = subtree:add(buffer(2,2),"The next two bytes")
    subtree:add(buffer(2,1),"The 3rd byte: " .. buffer(2,1):uint())
    subtree:add(buffer(3,1),"The 4th byte: " .. buffer(3,1):uint())

    -- this works OK
    --mycustomfnc(buffer, subtree)

    -- this fails:
    srcfncall="mycustomfnc(buffer, subtree)"
    loadstring(srcfncall)()
    -- result:
    --Lua Error: [string "mycustomfnc(buffer, subtree)"]:1: attempt to call global 'mycustomfnc' (a nil value)

end

-- load the udp.port table
udp_table = DissectorTable.get("udp.port")
-- register our protocol to handle udp port xxxx
udp_table:add(5001,trivial_proto)
```

What I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably wireshark runs multiple Lua VMs in parallel to speed up processing.  Each Lua VM has its own globals.

Comment: Try to pass your function as upvalue: Define `function mycustomfnc` as `local function mycustomfnc` and replace `srcfncall="mycustomfnc(buffer, subtree)"` with `srcfncall="(...)(buffer, subtree)"` and `loadstring(srcfncall)()` with `loadstring(srcfncall)(mycustomfnc)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I tried the changes you suggested, and it didn't work. But even if it did, notice that having in the code ```loadstring(srcfncall)(``` **```mycustomfnc```**  ```)``` defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve, i.e. having the function call stored as a string and thus modifiable at run time.

Comment: OK, you want to modify it at runtime.  Before changing from `"mycustomfnc(buffer, subtree)"` to `"mycustomfnc2(buffer, subtree)"` you should somehow define the function `mycustomfnc2`.  How would you do that?  Is it a pure Lua function?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  For the moment let's say I don't need to dynamically define the function, only the call to the function. Certainly there will be more than one function, but I don't think they're necessary to reproduce the problem. Let's keep it simple :-)

Comment: It looks like only objects you have explicitly registered are copied between Lua VMs.  Global variables are not copied.